# Print matching lines to a file

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I've been wrestling with this one as well. I have a file where I want to redirect all lines that begin with a `"` (single quote) to another file.

```
line1
"\line2
line3
"!line4
"Line5
```

I have tried `grep`, `sed`, `awk`. I have only been able to remove lines that begin with a match but have not been able to redirect to another file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep '^"' infile >outfile
```

The `^"` matches all lines beginning with a `"`.  The single quotes around it protects the double quote from messing with your shell.

Comment: Could have swore I tried that but I see what the problem is now. I have one space before the start of each line.Couldn't see it until I made a new file manually.